# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringApp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

So hello every one I tried to find solutions for my code from the other propositions but in vain :/ So here is my code lookin for help :/
spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


   <context:component-scan base-package="com.pfa.controller" />
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
   <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <display-name>FirstSpringApp</display-name> 
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
              org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  </web-app>
```

LoginController

```
 package com.pfa.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller

public class LoginController {
@RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");

    return model;
 }


   @RequestMapping(value="/submitadmissionForm.html", method =   RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@RequestParam Map<String,String>  reqPar) {

    String name = reqPar.get("studentName");
    String hobby = reqPar.get("hobby");

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
    model.addObject("msg","Details submitted by you:: Name: "+name+ ",   Hobby: " + hobby);

    return model;
    }

 }
```

AdmissionForm.html

```
<html>
<body>
 <h1> STUDENT ADMISSION FORM FOR ENGINEERING COURSES</h1>

 <form action="/FirstSpringApp/submitadmissionForm.html" method="post">
    <p>
        Student's Name : <input type="text" name="studentName" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Student's Hobby : <input type="text" name="studentHobby" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit this form by clicking here" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

AdmissionSucces.html

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <h1>Congratulations!! the Engineering college has processed your      Application form successfully</h1>

<h2>${msgddd}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which URL are you trying to hit? Post the exact log message from Spring **in** your question.

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post answers that aren't answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/FirstSpringApp")
public class LoginController {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` replace `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`
2. change suffix ".jsp" to ".html"
3. just set `@RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Answer (score 0):

Where have you mapped FirstSpringApp in Web.xml file? I guess, the URL is getting created is `http://<IP>:<PORT>/<CONTROLLER_URL>`.

Eg:

`http://localhost:9090/submitAdminssionForm`

Comment: Actually I mapped firstSpringAPP  here : @Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/FirstSpringApp")
public class LoginController {
 @RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm", method = RequestMethod.GET.... }I think the url shoud be http://localhost:9000/FirstSpringApp/submitAdmissionForm . and whar I foud even more confusing I can t get the for when I try to execute AdmissionForm.jsp !! :(